# Elasticsearch NEST API Version 7.7

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How does one use the new Elasticsearch 7.7 Async Background search facility using the NEST Library 7.7

It seems this feature is available only in X-Pack.

Does one need to buy a separate licence if we are already have a cloud Elastic subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Async Search feature is part of the basic license if you install on-premises and part of the standard license if you use the elastic cloud, there is no need to buy or upgrade your license.

You can see the on-premises license differences [here](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) and the cloud subscription differences [here](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/service/pricing)

But, the Async Search API is not implemented in the NEST client yet, according to this [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/4637), which is still open.

Comment: async search APIs will be in the next client release

Comment: Async search APIs are in 7.7.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/7.7.1

Comment: @RussCam Is there any docs on how to use this feature using NEST?

Comment: There are the Elasticsearch reference docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/async-search.html

Comment: @RussCam Are there any examples using the NEST api?

Comment: There aren't doc examples, but there are tests that demonstrate usage, calling `submit`, `get` then `delete`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/tests/Tests/XPack/AsyncSearch/AsyncSearchApiTests.cs